# Manhwa where the female lead is transported into a novel, gets drunk, signs up to become empress

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for the name of a manwha I read. It's a historical manhwa where the female lead gets transported into the world of a novel. There, she is a commoner and has a fiancé, but her fiancé cheats on her with a noble. When she's drunk, she signs up to be a candidate to become the empress; she's confused when she's actually chosen to become a candidate but I think in the end she ends up becoming empress.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Does this manhwa have any science fiction or fantasy elements? If not, then I'm afraid this question is off-topic here.

Comment: I mean I guess it does since the fl lead actually got transported in a novel

Comment: Oh, by "I'm pretty sure she's in a novel", you meant that she actually got transported into the world of the novel? Sorry, that wasn't clear to me. In that case, this is in fact on-topic.

Comment: Ye, she got transported into the world of the novel

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I think she was a brunette

Comment: His Majesty's Proposal - Reincarnated; sleeps with emperor. No breakup. A Tipsy Marriage Proposal for the Emperor - Not reincarnated, proposes to emperor after a breakup. I Stole the Male Lead's First Night - Reincarnated; sleeps with duke. No breakup I remember. None of these have commoner protagonist, or "signing up". None are good matches unless there are misremembered details.